# How to give command line options to PDFBox

Tags: python, command-line, pdfbox

What is the best way to give command-line arguments to pdfbox jar?

```
command_args = ['java', '-jar', config.PDF_BOX_JAR, 'ExtractText', '-console', '-encoding UTF-8', file_path]
```

Is there anything wrong with the above command?

Comment: Seems good, but have you verified that java exists, and that the pdfbox-app jar exists in the path?

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: Actually this command did not return any error. However, I am unable to verify whether the object returned has a proper "UTF-8" encoding.@furas

Comment: The command, if it runs, produces a text file. Are you asking how to find out whether the text file is utf-8 encoded? Then take a PDF that has something that you know isn't ASCII and then look at the TXT file with a hex editor.